# Button code doesn't make grids visible

Tags: c#, wpf

I have 4 buttons and and 4 grids. On 1st button click: grid 1's `visibilty.visible`. On second button click, grid 1's visibility is set to hidden and grid 2's visibility is set to visible. On button 3, the previous two grids' visibility is set to hidden and grid3 is set to visible. On 4th button, the previous three grids' visibility is set to hidden and grid 4 is made visible.

Now when I click button 3 or button 2, it doesn't get the relative grids to be visible. what to do?

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                Login.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                mainGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

            }

            private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                PanelGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                viewRoomsGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }

            private void btnEmployee_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                PanelGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                viewRoomsGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                EmployeeGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }

            private void btnCheckin1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                PanelGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                viewRoomsGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                EmployeeGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                CheckinGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }

            private void btnCheckout_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                PanelGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                viewRoomsGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                EmployeeGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                CheckinGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                CheckoutGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
```

Comment: But do you have an understandable question? [How to ask a question on StackOverflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: code please ... or else it is difficult give solution ...

Comment: Some kind of picture would be helpful, the question is confusing.

Comment: I have two arms and two legs respectively.

Comment: I have provided the code now for buttons

Comment: Ho gya hai thanks :)